# Is there any way to avoid the ["screen" is not defined Pylance] in Pygame Zero?

Tags: python, pylance

```py
import pgzrun

def draw():
    screen.draw.text("Hello World", topleft=(10, 10))

pgzrun.go()
```

[image]

Is there any way to avoid the *"screen" is not defined Pylance*?

This code does succeed in execution.

[image]

"screen" is a **global variable** in "\Lib\site-packages\pgzero\game.py".
Can't I avoid this warning?

Windows10 Pro 64bit
Visual Studio Code 1.60.1
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.7)

Comment: But, `screen` is not defined!

Comment: I can run it successfully.

Comment: `from pgzero.game import screen`

Comment: It really uses a less beautiful way to push `screen` into the namespace. :-/

Comment: @PeterWood  
After adding a line like this, the warning message disappeared. Thanks.
However, I am getting the following error
  `File "...\lib\site-packages\pgzero\game.py", line 73, in reinit_screen
    self.mod.screen.surface = self.screen
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'surface'`
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just below the import(s), add a hint to tell your tooling what to expect:

```
screen: pgzero.screen.Screen
```